# Solving Lights out for AI Course

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dijkstra, depth-first-search, a-star

So I was given the following task: Given that all lights in a 5x5 version of a game are turned on, write an algorithm using UCS / A* / BFS / Greedy best first search that finds a solution.

What I did first was realize that UCS would be unnecessary as the cost from moving from one state to another is 1(pressing a button that flips itself and neighbouring ones). So what I did is wrote BFS instead. It turned out that it works too long and fills up a queue, even though I was paying attention to removing parent nodes when I was finished with them not to overflow the memory. It would work for around 5-6mins and then crash because of memory.
Next, what I did is write DFS(even though it was not mentioned as one of possibilities) and it did find a solution in 123 secs, at depth 15(I used depth-first limited because I knew that there was a solution at depth 15).

What I am wondering now is am I missing something? Is there some good heuristics to try to solve this problem using A* search? I figured out absolutely nothing when it's about heuristics, because it doesn't seem any trivial to find one in this problem.

Thanks very much. Looking forward to some help from you guys

Here is my source code(I think it's pretty straightforward to follow):

```
struct state
{
    bool board[25];
    bool clicked[25];
    int cost;
    int h;
    struct state* from;
};

int visited[1<<25];
int dx[5] = {0, 5, -5};
int MAX_DEPTH = 1<<30;
bool found=false;

struct state* MakeStartState()
{
    struct state* noviCvor = new struct state();

    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) noviCvor->board[i] = false, noviCvor->clicked[i] = false;
    noviCvor->cost = 0;
    //h=...
    noviCvor->from = NULL;

    return noviCvor;
};

struct state* MakeNextState(struct state* temp, int press_pos)
{
    struct state* noviCvor = new struct state();

    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) noviCvor->board[i] = temp->board[i], noviCvor->clicked[i] = temp->clicked[i];
    noviCvor->clicked[press_pos] = true;

    noviCvor->cost = temp->cost + 1;
    //h=...
    noviCvor->from = temp;

    int temp_pos;

    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
        temp_pos = press_pos + dx[k];

        if(temp_pos >= 0 && temp_pos < 25)
        {
            noviCvor->board[temp_pos] = !noviCvor->board[temp_pos];
        }
    }

    if( ((press_pos+1) % 5 != 0) && (press_pos+1) < 25 )
        noviCvor->board[press_pos+1] = !noviCvor->board[press_pos+1];

    if( (press_pos % 5 != 0) && (press_pos-1) >= 0 )
        noviCvor->board[press_pos-1] = !noviCvor->board[press_pos-1];

    return noviCvor;
};

bool CheckFinalState(struct state* temp)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        if(!temp->board[i]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int bijection_mapping(struct state* temp)
{
    int temp_pow = 1;
    int mapping = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        if(temp->board[i])
            mapping+=temp_pow;

        temp_pow*=2;
    }

    return mapping;
}

void BFS()
{
    queue<struct state*> Q;

    struct state* start = MakeStartState();
    Q.push(start);
    struct state* temp;
    visited[ bijection_mapping(start) ] = 1;

    while(!Q.empty())
    {
        temp = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        visited[ bijection_mapping(temp) ] = 2;

        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            if(!temp->clicked[i])
            {
                struct state* next = MakeNextState(temp, i);
                int mapa = bijection_mapping(next);

                if(visited[ mapa ] == 0)
                {
                    if(CheckFinalState(next))
                    {
                        printf("NADJENO RESENJE\n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    visited[ mapa ] = 1;
                    Q.push(next);
                }
            }
        }

        delete temp;
    }
}
```

PS. As I am not using map anymore(switched to array) for visited states, my DFS solution improved from 123 secs to 54 secs but BFS still crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you may already recognize that in *Lights Out* you never have to flip the same switch more than once, and it doesn't matter in which order you flip the switches.  You can thus describe the current state in two distinct ways: either in terms of which lights are on, or in terms of which switches have been flipped.  The latter, together with the starting pattern of lights, gives you the former.

To employ a graph-search algorithm to solve the problem, you need a notion of adjacency.  That follows more easily from the second characterization: two states are adjacent if there is exactly one switch about which they they differ.  That characterization also directly encodes the length of the path to each node (= the number of switches that have been flipped), and it reduces the number of subsequent moves that need to be considered for each state considered, since all possible paths to each node are encoded in the pattern of switches.

You could use that in a breadth-first search relatively easily (and this may be what you in fact tried).  BFS is equivalent to Dijkstra's algorithm in that case, even without using an explicit priority queue, because you enqueue new nodes to explore in priority (path-length) order.

You can also convert that to an A* search with addition of a suitable heuristic.  For example, since each move turns off at most five lights, one could take as the heuristic the number of lights still on after each move, divided by 5.  Though that's a bit crude, I'm inclined to think that it would be of some help.  You do need a real priority queue for that alternative, however.

As far as implementation goes, do recognize that you can represent both the pattern of lights currently on and the pattern of switches that have been pressed as bit vectors.  Each pattern fits in a 32-bit integer, and a list of visited states requires 2<sup>25</sup> bits, which is well within the capacity of modern computing systems.  Even if you use that many *bytes*, instead, you ought to be able to handle it.  Moreover, you can perform all needed operations using bitwise arithmetic operators, especially XOR.  Thus, this problem (at its given size) ought to be computable relatively quickly.

**Update:**

As I mentioned in comments, I decided to solve the problem for myself, with -- it seemed to me -- very good success.  I used a variety of techniques to achieve good performance and minimize memory usage, and in this case, those mostly were complementary.  Here are some of my tricks:

- I represented each whole-system state with a single `uint64_t`.  The top 32 bits contain a bitmask of which switches have been flipped, and the bottom 32 contain a bitmask of which lights are on as a result.  I wrapped these in a `struct` along with a single pointer to link them together as elements of a queue.  A given state can be tested as a solution with one bitwise-and operation and one integer comparison.
- I created a pre-initialized array of 25 `uint64_t` bitmasks representing the effect of each move.  One bit set among the top 32 of each represents the switch that is flipped, and between 3 and five bits set among the bottom 32 represent the lights that are toggled as a result.  The effect of flipping one switch can then be computed simply as `new_state = old_state ^ move[i]`.
- I implemented *plain* breadth-first search instead of A*, in part because I was trying to put something together quickly, and in particular because that way I could use a regular queue instead of a priority queue.
- I structured my BFS in a way that naturally avoided visiting the same state twice, without having to actually *track* which states had ever been enqueued.  This was based on some insight into how to efficiently generate distinct bit patterns without repeating, with those having fewer bits set generated before those having more bits set.  The latter criterion was satisfied fairly naturally by the queue-based approach required anyway for BFS.
- I used a second (plain) queue to recycle dynamically-allocated queue nodes after they were removed from the main queue, to minimize the number calls to `malloc()`.

Overall code was a bit less than 200 lines, including blank and comment lines, data type declarations, I/O, queue implementation (plain C, no STL) -- everything.

Note, by the way, that the priority queue employed in standard Dijkstra and in A* is primarily about *finding the right answer* (shortest path), and only secondarily about doing so efficiently.  Enqueueing and dequeueing from a standard queue can both be `O(1)`, whereas those operations on a priority queue are `o(log m)` in the number of elements in the queue.  A* and BFS both have worst-case queue size upper bounds of `O(n)` in the total number of states.  Thus, BFS will scale better than A* with problem size; the only question is whether the former reliably gives you the right answer, which in this case, it does.

Comment: FWIW, I decided to solve the problem for myself.  I used a simple breadth-first search along the lines described above, written in C.  It found a 15-move solution in about 0.5 seconds (on a fairly hefty machine).

Comment: What you described is exactly all I did, I mean the ideas, along with the heuristics for A* that came into my mind after I wrote this text. The thing is, I guess I was using too much space for storing my structures and therefore my program worked slowly. I stored both the board state and presses state and didn't let the state transit into next state by pressing the same button that was pressed before. The thing is, I stored them as arrays of bools of size 25, so in my case, it is bytes. What I guess eats my time is tracking visited states,I used map.I will try to optimize things later. Thanks!

Comment: So I posted my source code in edit. Could you people please take a look at it ? Thanks in advance. Ps. Even though I'm not using map anymore it still crashes after some time of working

Comment: @LukaBulatovic, I'm not up for performing a detailed analysis of your code, but I updated my answer with a description of some of the techniques I employed in my solution to make it efficient.  Although you may have built yours around an equivalent algorithm, it looks like the details are a lot more cumbersome.

Comment: @LukaBulatovic, by the way, I added a bit of instrumentation to check memory usage, and found that the high-water mark for my queue was about 5.2 million elements (of >32 million total possible states).  For my 16-byte elements, that amounts to around 80 MB.